# How to add names to an array of unnamed JSON objects?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, csv

So I'm currently using csvtojson in order to convert a csv file to, well, json, and my code is returning an array of unnamed objects. However, I want these objects to be named. More specifically, I want to use the values from the first column in order to name the objects.

My CSV file looks like this:

> First Name, Restaurant, Food Name, Comment, Price
>
> Andrew, Clucky's Chicken, Chickenator, This sandwich is awesome, $9.99
>
> Michelle, Bytes, Big Burger, Burger was too well done, $12.99
>
> Cam, Candyland, Yummy Gummies, Good price for bulk candy, $1.75

I'm using this code and running it in node:

```
// require the csvtojson converter class
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
//create a new converter object
var converter = new Converter({});

//call the fromFile function which takes in the path to the csv file, as well as a callback function
converter.fromFile("./restaurants.csv", function(err,result){
  // if an error has occurred, then handle it
  if(err){
    console.log("An error has occurred");
    console.log(err);
  }
  // create a variable called json and store the result of the conversion
  var json = result;

  // log our json to verify it has worked
  console.log(json);
});
```

Which returns:

```
[ { 'First Name': 'Andrew',
    'Restaurant': 'Clucky's Chicken', 
    'Food Name': 'Chickenator',
    'Comment': 'This sandwich is awesome',
    'Price': '$9.99' },
  { 'First Name': 'Michelle',
    'Restaurant': 'Bytes', 
    'Food Name': 'Big Burger',
    'Comment': 'Burger was too well done',
    'Price': '$12.99' },
  { 'First Name': 'Cam',
    'Restaurant': 'Candyland', 
    'Food Name': 'Yummy Gummies',
    'Comment': 'Good price for bulk candy',
    'Price': '$1.75' } ]
```

But I would like it to return something more along the lines of:

```
[ Andrew : { 'Restaurant': 'Clucky's Chicken', 
             'Food Name': 'Chickenator',
             'Comment': 'This sandwich is awesome',
             'Price': '$9.99' },
  Michelle : { 'Restaurant': 'Bytes', 
               'Food Name': 'Big Burger',
               'Comment': 'Burger was too well done',
               'Price': '$12.99' },
  Cam : { 'Restaurant': 'Candyland', 
          'Food Name': 'Yummy Gummies',
          'Comment': 'Good price for bulk candy',
          'Price': '$1.75' } ]
```

Anybody have any suggestions on how I can do this?

Comment: The outer brackets should be curly, not square. Square indicates an array, which doesn't (usually) have named properties like `property: "value"`. Curly is an object, which is more suited to your needs.

Comment: Oh, ok. In that case maybe I don't need named objects at all. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: You're welcome. And you wouldn't need named objects, per se, more properties of an object with the name as the key and the value as the object.

Comment: I'm not sure if I quite understand what the difference is...

Comment: I took Stanley Cheung's answer and modified it slightly to get the curly braces on the outside, so instead of var itemArray = [ ], I made it var items = { }... I guess I just don't know what the difference is between named objects and "properties of an object with the name as the key and the value as the object"

Comment: Well, there's not really such a thing as a named object. An object can't have a name attached to it; its apparent name is either the variable name it's stored in (`var objectName = {key:"value"};`) or the object property it's stored in (var outerObject = {objectName:{key:"value"}};). The latter is what I meant by "properties of an object with the name as the key and the value as the object." You can see that objectName, the name of the object, is the key, while `{key:"value"}` is the object, and it is the value associated with the key.

Comment: Also, I should've said "and the **object** as the **value**" (I accidentally switched them).

Comment: Thank you!  I get it now :D

Comment: You're welcome! Glad to help someone else learn Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a custom function (since you want to convert `array` into a `map`).

```
function arrayToMap(array) {
  var map = {};

  array.map(
    (element) => {
      var firstName = element['First Name'];
      delete element['First Name'];
      map[firstName] = element;          
    }    
  );
  return map;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I can't get this one to work properly :( I tried throwing in a console.log(map) but nothing is showing.

Comment: Nit-picky: note that while you've called it a "map", it's not, it's just an `Object`. [`Map` is a new ES6 type.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map). The solution is, of course, otherwise fine.

Comment: Try to replace `forEach` with `map`

Comment: @msanford True, but we _can_ look at an `object` like a sort of map since it can access properties via keys. That is why I referenced it as a map.

Comment: @AnteJablanAdamović I agree, of course, and I prefixed my comment as being openly nit-picky. I mention it only for completeness because there exists a Map type in ES6. :)

Answer (score 2):

Create a new array `itemArray`, then loop for all item in array and push it to `itemArray`

```
var itemArray = []
a.map(item => {
    firstName = item["First Name"];
    delete item["First Name"];
    itemArray[firstName] = item;
})
console.log(itemArray); // <<<< you get the result here
```